# Environment-specific properties are not loaded in Micronaut

Tags: java, micronaut

I am trying to load the environment-specific properties using Micronaut 3. I have two files `application.yml` and `application-dev.yml`

**application.yml**

```
micronaut:
  security:
    authentication: bearer
    token:
      jwt:
        signatures:
          jwks:
            IdentityServer:
              url: 'https://localhost:5001/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks'
```

**application-dev.yml**

```
micronaut:
  security:
    authentication: bearer
    token:
      jwt:
        signatures:
          jwks:
            identityServer:
              url: 'https://falconidentity.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks'
```

trying to access the URL

```
@ConfigurationProperties("micronaut.security.token.jwt.signatures.jwks.identityServer")
public record OAuthProperties(String url) {
}

 var ctx = ApplicationContext.run();
        var teamConfiguration = ctx.getBean(OAuthProperties.class);
```

In the teamConfiguration variable I am able to see the value from the `application.yml` file not from the `application-dev.yml` file.

As I know by default Micronaut only looks for application.yml. Then, for tests,dev and prod, it loads application.yml and overrides any values there with the ones defined in application-test.yml, application-dev.yml and application-prod.yml.However, this is not working for me.

I have setup the default environment as well

```
Micronaut.build(args)
                .mainClass(ApiGateway.class)
                .defaultEnvironments("dev")
                .start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't setting the default environment here

```
ApplicationContext.run();
```

That is why

Comment: Found this blog, other here they are not setting ApplicationContext.run() https://sergiodelamo.com/blog/application-dev-enviornment.html

Answer (score 0):

You create a second application without environment instead of using the existing one with "dev" environment.

You can inject the existing context instead of creating a new one

```
@Inject
ApplicationContext applicationContext;
```

Comment: I am quite not clear with You create a second application without environment instead of using the existing one with "dev" environment. Can you please provide more details

Comment: Actual I don't want to set the default environment, when I run the application from IDE it should pick up dev.

Comment: `ApplicationContext.run()`  and `Micronaut.build(args).mainClass(ApiGateway.class).defaultEnvironments("dev").start();` are two code blocks that create two independent Micronaut contexts. First one uses the application.yml and second one uses the application-dev.yml as configuration. In the OAuthProperties.java you use the first context.

Comment: I am still not clear, my understanding was by default Micronaut only looks for application.yml. Then, for tests, dev, and prod, it loads application.yml and overrides any values there with the ones defined in application-test.yml, application-dev.yml, and application-prod.yml

Comment: Check this blog https://sergiodelamo.com/blog/application-dev-enviornment.html